# "NOT NULL" column in Paradox DB?

Tags: sql, syntax-error, bde, paradox

Is there any way to prevent a null-fields in Paradox? When I try i exec.

```
CREATE TABLE  "users" (
user_id INTEGER NOT NULL
)
```

I get Capability not supported. (BDE error 12289). When there is no "NOT NULL" args - it's OK.
P.S. I work in SQL explorer (borland one), and I can't change it, cause it's part of the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to prevent a null-fields in Paradox is to just create the table.

There is in fact no way to *create* null-fields in Paradox.  Unlike most modern databases, the BDE does not allow or recognize NULLs.

Paradox local SQL does not allow a NOT NULL constraint because it would not make any sense.  Every table field is always NOT NULL.

Paradox table structure *does* include a constraint to disallow BLANKs, but you cannot set it from a SQL statement.  And a BLANK is a very different thing from a NULL.

See also this question
[How does Paradox manage null and empty values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228123/how-does-paradox-manage-null-and-empty-values)